# Is impression tracking data available in a data view?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

Is impression tracking data available in a data view? If so what is data view name?

Comment: Wont this come under `link name` in click activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no data view that exposes impression region tracking. You only have data extracts and reports providing info on impressions. You could potentially use a data extract to import the data back into a data extension, but there is no standard data view available.

Answer (score 6):

There is limited/scattered information in the sfmc documentation regarding the impression region and tracking.

However I will layout and consolidate all the relevant information from the sfmc help & documentation page.

**Data Extract**

[- Impression Region through Click](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/clickimpression/)

[- SendJob Impression](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/sendjobimpression/)

[- Send Impression over time](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/tracking_extract_output/sentimpression/)

**Reports**

[- Impression Region in Triggered Sends](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/reports/email_reports/impression_tracking_for_triggered_sends_report/)

[- Impression Tracking by Job](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/reports/email_reports/region_performance_for_triggered_sends_over_time_report/)

[- Region Performance Over Time](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/reports/email_reports/region_performance_over_time_report/)

> Note: The solution post will be updated with further information if
>   found.

Comment: +1 as this is a great consolidation, but is potentially a 'link-only" answer. I would recommend adding in some small snippets from these links to make sure this answer is still relevant, even if the links become broken.